# How to find total rows when using cloudant find api

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I have a find query as given below

```
POST /movies/_find HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 168
Host: localhost:5984

{
    "selector": {
        "year": {"$gt": 2010}
    },
    "fields": ["_id", "_rev", "year", "title"],
    "sort": [{"year": "asc"}],
    "limit": 2,
    "skip": 0
}
```

Which returns the first two results that match the query. Is it possible to get the total number of rows with this query. This is very useful when building pagination

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. In order to do so, the query would need to trawl the whole set to count. Note that text indexes already support pagination out of the box:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#finding-documents-by-using-an-index

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using search API and it returned total rows

Answer (score 1):

You can get meta data of the DB using GET /movies

total number of rows - "doc_count"

Response example:

```
    {
      "update_seq": "<some data>",
      "db_name": "movies",
      "sizes": {
        "file": <size>,
        "external": <size>,
        "active": <size>
      },
      "purge_seq": 0,
      "other": {
        "data_size": <size>
      },
      "doc_del_count": <number>,
      "doc_count": <number>,
      "disk_size": <size>,
      "disk_format_version": <version>,
      "compact_running": false,
      "instance_start_time": "0"
    }
```

Comment: how to apply `"selector": { "year": {"$gt": 2010} }` for this